# R Visual Text Appears in Power BI .pbix but Not in Online Applicataion

Tags: r, powerbi

I wrote script for my R visual which works on my local pbix file, but some text is missing when I turn it into an application online (or even in my online workspace). The text is "Author_Country..."

pbix: [image]

app/workspace: [image]

(Note: it is okay that there are different number of papers here.)

This is my code within Power BI R visual:

```
library(metafor)
library(ggplot2)

if(nrow(dataset) == 0) {
    ggplot(dataset) +
  geom_point(aes(x = dataset$yi, y = dataset$sei)) +
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "No Meta-Analysis for this Combination of Variables", subtitle = NULL, caption = NULL) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = -15, size = 16, family = "Arial"),
        plot.title.position = "plot")
} else {
    resFE <- rma(yi = dataset$yi, sei = dataset$sei, method = "FE", data = dataset)
    
    forest(resFE, atransf = exp, at = log(c(0.05, 0.25, 1, 4)), xlim = c(-6, 4),
       slab = paste(dataset$LeadAuthor, '_', dataset$Country, '_', dataset$Season, ' (', dataset$Unique, ')'),
       header = c('Author_Country_Season_(ID)', 'Odds Ratio [95% CI]'),
       cex = 0.75, xlab = 'Odds Ratio (log scale)',
       mlab = '',
       cex.main = 1)
       
       text(-6, -1, pos = 4, cex = 0.75, bquote(paste('Fixed Effect Model (Q = ',
                                               .(formatC(resFE$QE, digits = 2, format = 'f')), ', df = ', .(resFE$k - resFE$p),
                                               ', p = ', .(formatC(resFE$QEp, digits = 2, format = 'f')), ';', I^2, '=',
                                               .(formatC(resFE$I2, digits = 1, format = 'f')), '%)')))
}
```

You can see that the dynamic slab title (the ones with name country season etc) work fine, but the standard text for header is not showing up.

Has anyone had this issue?

Thanks